# How to add //@dart=2.9 in dart file

Tags: flutter, dart-null-safety

Now I'm working in flutter project.
I need to add //@dart=2.9 in dart file.
But i got run time error. Like A library can't opt out of null safety by default,when using sound null safety.
How can i add it on dart file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add it at the top of main.dart.

then run
$ flutter clean
$ flutter pub get

if this does not work,check this https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
//@dart=2.9
Import 'package: flutter/material. Dart';

class dart extends StatefulWidget {
  dart ({Key key}): super (key: key);
  @override
  _dartState createState () => _dartState();
}

class _dartState extends State<dart> {
  @override
  Widget builds (BuildContext context) => Scaffold();
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

from dart 3 update, @dart=2.9 doesn't work.